# Angular2 PreloadingStrategy not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to understand how this [custom route preloading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#custom-preloading) works in angular2. But I just cant get it working in the first place.

Here's my code

**custom.preloading-strategy.ts**

```
export class CustomPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
    preload(route: Route, fn: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
        console.log("Preloading...");
        return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).flatMap(_ => fn());
    }
}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        data: {
            preload: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
            preload: true
        }
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [
    CustomPreloadingStrategy
];

export const routeComponents: any[] = [
    HomeComponent
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    preloadingStrategy: CustomPreloadingStrategy,
    useHash: true
});
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [appRoutingProviders, appServices],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SharedComponents,
        appDirectives,
        routeComponents,
        NewsMediaListComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
```

**deps**

```
"@angular/common": "2.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
"@angular/core": "2.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
"@angular/http": "2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
"@angular/router": "3.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.1",
```

However, there's no error or whatsoever in the logs. And I don't know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2):

The Lazy loading only works with modules.

So this doesn't work if you only use `HomeComponent` in your route as component. Instead of the component-attribute you should create your own module for the `HomeComponent` and use `loadChildren` in the route (**app.routing.ts**):

```
{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './../home/home.module#HomeModule',
    data: { preload: true }
}
```

Create another module in a separate file (**home.module.ts**):

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { routing } from './home.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

And create the routing file for this component (**home.routing.ts**):

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

const homeRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
]

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(
    homeRoutes
);
```

The `data: { preload: true }` can only be used at a route that has an attribute `loadChildren`. You can still set the data-attribute for any other route but then it has nothing to do with lazy loading itself.

> You should read this well-written [article of Victor Savkin](https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-preloading-modules-ba3c75e424cb#.qfh6b7cm3) about lazy loading modules.

---

**Updated answer:**
I also see that `data: { preload: true }` won't work because you need to handle this in your custom preloading strategy like this:

```
export class SelectedPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
    preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
        return route.data && route.data['preload'] ? load() :  Observable.of(null);
    }
 }
```

What you also need to do is to export this preloading strategy to use it in your app.module in the providers array:

in **app.routing.ts**:

```
export const APP_ROUTES_MODULE_PROVIDER = [SelectedPreloadingStrategy];
```

and import it in **app.module.ts**:

```
import { routing, APP_ROUTES_MODULE_PROVIDER } from './app.routing';
```

to the `@NgModule`-providers-array:

```
providers: [
    ...
    APP_ROUTES_MODULE_PROVIDER
],
```

If everthing compiles correctly and you route to the lazy loaded module in your application you should check the `Network`-Tab of your Developer Tools and you'll see that the router has loaded the module only after you have navigated to it.

Comment: I've actually got the example from that article. However, I tried your exact solution as well by using another name for module and component (`TestComponent` and `TestModule`) but yet I still don't get my `console.log`. This is the same behavior whether I use `component` or `loadChildren` in my `appRoutes`, the debugger breaks in `preload` line and not executing the scripts inside it.

Comment: The difference in your edited solution is just to import the `PreloadingStrategy` into app routes `providers`. Actually, in my original question, I have included it beforehand, and also I have included it in my router module `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: CustomPreloadingStrategy, useHash: true });`. This hasn't worked for me yet.

Answer (score 1):

You want to define your strategy the same way the PreloadAllModules modules strategy that only preloads the modules selected. So you should be used the loadChildren properly in route as:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './app/home.module#HomeModule',
        data: {
          preload: true
        }
    }
];
```

Also, you please take a look at [Custom Pre-loading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#custom-preloading) again and an example for creating a custom Pre-Loading strategy at [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/S7ZRQPNwpupEG9IQxy8p?p=preview).